# Restructuring old Flyway migrations

Tags: spring, database, flyway

I'm using Spring Boot 3 and Flyway to handle my db migrations. There are a bunch of old migrations which have already been deployed to databases.

Can I restructure the flyway migration folders (=change the paths for the migration files) or does it cause some checksum failures in next deployment? I would not change the filenames nor the content of the files.

Comment: Why you don't try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only the name and content that are used the checksum so you should be ok. Worked in previous workflows where current migrations were under `db/migration` and part of the release flow was to put them in their own folders afterwards. Dev and Test databases never had an issue with the moves.

Comment: Thank you @Barry! I did the change and can now confirm that it did cause any harm.